# Is there a way to create an AES cipher from a hashed key-secret?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes

Having lost the plaintext secret, but having the hashed key, it's posible to encript and decript in openssl like so (keys and iv are not the actual ones):

Input:

```
printf "ciphertext" | base64 -d | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -nosalt -K "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" -iv "00"
```

Output:

"plaintext"

Now, to be able to do this in a NodeJs application, openssl is called as child_process. As you can guess, spawning openssl calls is not very performant.

To be able to do it in node crypto, the plaintext "secret" is needed in creating the keys.

Is there a way yo generate the cipher from the hashed key?

I have tried doing it like so with no succes.

```
var crypto=require('crypto')
var iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 0);
var key = '0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
var cipher=crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', newBuffer(key).toString('binary'), new Buffer('0000000000000000', 'hex').toString('binary'));
var enc = cipher.update("ciphertext", 'base64', 'utf8')
enc += cipher.final('utf8')
console.log(enc);
```

Output:

```
internal/crypto/cipher.js:164
  const ret = this._handle.final();
                           ^
Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
new Buffer('0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000', 'hex')
```

for the key and and

```
new Buffer('00000000000000000000000000000000', 'hex')
```

for the IV. Currently you are encoding to a binary string representation of the bytes, instead of (just) decoding the hexadecimal values to 32 bytes and 16 bytes respectively.

To use this you should use `createDecipheriv` as `createDecipher` will still generate the key using the password.

Comment: It works from node to node like this, but not from openssl to node.
Ill keep working on it, thanks.

Comment: Check if it is just the initial block that is wrong, the IV is derived as well, it is not set to all zero's when deriving the key (and the IV) from the password. One problem: you'd need to have saved it as you cannot recalculate it from the key and ciphertext.

Comment: Iv is something like "9A00000000000000", it's not actually al 0's, but still, the iv seems irrelevant because im getting the same encription output with, without or with different ivs.

Comment: I finally did it using createCipheriv and createDecipheriv respectively. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah, OK, interesting. I didn't notice that you gave the IV without calling the specialized function for that. So do I assume correctly that for `createDecipher` without `iv` the IV is used, but the key is still derived from the password?

Comment: The iv has no effect whatsoever, if it's not within createDecipheriv, that's what i conclude at least.